# show item on specific table cell on hover in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

```
<td *ngFor="let tbh of tblH; let i=index" on-mouseover="hoveredI=i" on- 
 mouseleave="hoveredI=-1">{{data[tbh]}}
 <div class="onHoverDiv" *ngIf="i==hoveredI">
   <ul>
     <li (click)="editCell(data,tbh);">
       <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</td>
```

this my HTML code to show edit icon on hover on specific table cell but the problem is its working but its show icon in all the particular column of table cell i want show edit icon on hover in specific table cell how this to be done

Comment: provide json data.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following css:

```
li.fa-pencil {
  display: none;
}

li:hover.fa-pencil {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: i want to show using ngIf and on table cell than div is show.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set one extra key `is_hover` into your array.set `is_hover` by default false.and just set below code.

you need to set like first in the component.

```
tblH.foreach((tbh,i)=>{tblh[i].is_hover = false})
```

**html**

```
<td *ngFor="let tbh of tblH; let i=index"  (mouseleave)="tbh.is_hover =!tbh.is_hover" (mouseenter)="tbh.is_hover =!tbh.is_hover">{{data[tbh]}}
 <div class="onHoverDiv" *ngIf="tbh.is_hover">
   <ul>
     <li (click)="editCell(data,tbh);">
       <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: have you set first is_hover?